# crossfading divs with constraints

Tags: jquery, html

i want to crossfade two divs with jquery.

That would be easy (kind of), if i didnt' have the following constraints:

1) the background div should be always visible.

2) there are other divs on-top, so: no z-index

3) it has to be responsive, so: no width, no height

**Example:**

```
<DIV1><pic1><pic2><pic3><...><pic n></DIV1>
<DIV2><pic1><pic2><...><pic n></DIV2>
```

1) Visible: DIV2 (on top of DIV1) -> Fade DIV2

2) Visible: DIV1 -> DIV2 next picture

3) Visible: DIV1 -> DIV2 fadein

4) Visible: DIV2 (on top of DIV1) -> DIV1 next picture

5) Visible: DIV2 (on top of DIV1) -> DIV2 fade out

repeat until last image in the DIV, then start from beginning.

---

Could you please help me find an elegant solution? Thnx in advance!

Comment: Please provide some of your jQuery workings so far.

Comment: you need it for many divs or for only this two?

Comment: I need it only for these two

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```html
<div class="fadeContainer">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item hidden">2</div>
  <div class="item hidden">3</div>
</div>
```

```css
.fadeContainer {
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.hidden { opacity: 0; }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideshow = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);
});
function nextSlide() {
  var items = $(".item").length,
      $current;
  $(".item").each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("hidden") ) {
      $current = $(this).addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
  if($(".item").last()[0] === $current[0]) {
    // loop back to first if this is the last slide
    $(".item").first().removeClass("hidden");
  }
  $current.next(".item").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

[CSSdeck example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/eay7iltz)

Comment: Thnx! Problem is, this won't work in explorer<10 - or am i wrong?

Comment: Damn IE... I guess `opacity` doesn't work with IE8 and you'll probably need a polyfill for `transition`. I think jQuery's `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` are IE compatible, but of course you'd need to modify the code a bit...

Comment: yup. tried that (fadeToggle()) - but then it doesn't crossfade anymore. still - thnx for your input!